# pip3 install mmdet giving an error failed to build pycocotools

Tags: pip, pycocotools

When installing OpenMMDetection toolbox, I try to install mmdet package but it gives the following erro.
I installed VSC++ 14.20 and following an error with "visual studio c++ 14.0 or greater required" message.[ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCJ2w.png)

So it is mostly giving an error to build pycocotools. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing a previous version of mmdet.

```
pip install mmdet==2.19.1
```